# NetworkInfo instantiation

Tags: android

[GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/net/NetworkInfo.java#NetworkInfo.%3Cinit%3E%28int,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) shows a constructor for NetworkInfo as

`public NetworkInfo(int type, int subtype, String typeName, String subtypeName)`

but i cant see it within eclipse. Is there a specific way to instantiate NetworkInfo (if it is possible at all) ?

Comment: why would you need to do that ?

Comment: I'm trying to unit test a class that uses `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();` which returns a NetworkInfo object.

Comment: you can create a dummy networkinfo subclass that returns what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor is hide. You can't instanciate it normally, but I think you can use reflection to use it.

From the source code

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
public NetworkInfo(int type, int subtype, String typeName, String subtypeName)
```

Comment: Check this link http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/10/28/code-examples-using-hidden-android-apis/

Comment: Thanks for the article. How do you pass multiple parameters into the reflected method in this particular case ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207283/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-method-in-java-reflections