# how to pass multiple parameters to a function using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, parameters

I am trying to create something similar to google which performs the folowing action.

The user searches with the student name and when he selects a specific student then a pop up menu opens with several of the student credentials.

I am able to fetch the data and with that data am calling a function in jquery which displays this data.

There are about 10 details that are being fetched from the database.

My jquery..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {'init_data' : 'title_wise','title_name': value_text},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        length_turns=data.split('$').length;
        while(num_turns<length_turns) {
            temp_data_value[num_turns++]=data.substring(0,data.indexOf('$'));
            if(num_turns==8)
                temp_data_value[num_turns-1]=data;
            temp_data_storage=data.substring(data.indexOf('$')+1);
            data=temp_data_storage;  }
```

and the function is..

```
function sample(data,data,data,data,data,data...........)
```

The data returned from the php is something like this..

```
echo fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data.'$'.fetched_data
```

The data is being fetched correctly and am able to view it..

The questions is, how should I pass these arguments to the function..should I pass them individually like

```
func(a[0],a[1].....)
```

or is there any other way of doing this like calling in a loop or doing something like this

[how to pass multiple parameters to a method in java reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207283/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-method-in-java-reflections)

Also, say I return the function call directly from php like

```
func(a[0],a[1]...)
```

to jquery and now can I directly call this as a function here ?

Comment: You should start using JSON, returning object from server and pass it to javascript method

Comment: thanks @wolff..can you please share some sample code on how should return from the php file..

Comment: There is already many many examples available online and currently im on tablet so not that great for posting any useful answer, im sorry...

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply `func.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])` ?

Comment: Use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), it's a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @guest271314 "apply" did the job..thanks.. :)